Как настроить управление геймпадом в i3wm на Arch Linux?
Хочется чутка удобнее управлять i3wm, и геймпад, как по мне, в данном случае будет удобнее, когда ты не хочешь сидеть близко к монитору, а просто откатиться к спинке стула.
Так вот: как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии, например, на RB (это на Xbox, на моём контроллере RB - это BTN_TL) переключался рабочий стол вправо? Нужно ли что-то дополнительно сделать, чтобы он воспринимал нажатия геймпада?
При release (я не знаю как это сказать по-русски) кнопки BTN_TL в evtest отображается следующая информация:
Event: time 1725477117.290452, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90007
Event: time 1725477117.290452, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 310 (BTN_TL), value 0

